# 401 ( Unauthorised ) error when using jQuery's $.get and GMail API

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail-api

I'm trying to run jQuery's $.get after having a user log in with the G+ API with javascript, but am getting a 401 ( unauthorised ) error in the browser console.

Here is the format of the url I am requesting: `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myusername%40gmail.com/messages?key=%7Bmyborwserapikey%7D`

I've also tried `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?key=%7Bmyborwserapikey%7D`

both are returning the 401 error after logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each request to the Gmail API requires an access token, so an API key will not be enough.

While the user may have logged in with the G+ API that does not by itself give your app authorized access to the user's Gmail.

Check here for more details on getting access to the Gmail API:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview#auth_and_the_gmail_api