# Any way to make AJAX calls to Gmail API without going through JS library?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, gmail-api

A simple guide to making a GET request to get a user's messages through Gmail API can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#request).

But the way we are instructed to do the request is in the following manner:

```
function getMessage(userId, messageId, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
    'userId': userId,
    'id': messageId
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

Is it possible to make the request using the good ol' `XMLHttpRequest` object on the client side? If so what parameters should be passed into the call?

I have tried this:

```
var getMessages = function() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
   if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
xhr.open( "GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages", true );
xhr.send();
 }
```

But I get a 401, even after authenticating.

Comment: I found this question which addresses a similar issue but with jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334746/401-unauthorised-error-when-using-jquerys-get-and-gmail-api. So I added `xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", userToken.access_token);` to my code but still getting a 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it states in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35435496/1819335), you should pass the access token as a query parameter with the name **access_token**, or prefix the authorization header value with "Bearer", like so:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + userToken.access_token);
```

Comment: ugh! I was so close! I never really understood why the word "Bearer" had to be included and what it meant so I'll read on it now so I don't forget again. Thank you!