# Email sent using Gmail API blocking gmail account occasionally

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API to send an email in Java.
Code works fine and I am able to send an email.

However, after a while, same code throws **401 unauthorized** exception and my gmail account gets blocked.

I got an email from Google :

> Action required: Your Google Account is temporarily disabled
>   
> Google has disabled your Account, XXXX@gmail.com, because of a violation of our [Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/).

What is the reason for this issue? Which Google service term is being violated?

Comment: are you sending too emails? maybe gmail is going classify you as spammer

Comment: According to the documentation, a problem with quota will result in HTTP 403 or HTTP 429. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Comment: I am not sending too many email. I am sending hardly 10-15 emails.. @ddb

Comment: @JulienCsj Thanks for the link. However, I am getting **HTTP 401 unauthorized** and as mentioned earlier, I am hardly sending 10-15 emails in a day

Answer (score 0):

As someone answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336197), each request to the Gmail API requires an access token, so an API key will not be enough.

While the user may have logged in with the G+ API that does not by itself give your app authorized access to the user's Gmail.

Check here for more details on getting access to the Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview#auth_and_the_gmail_api

Comment: Appreciate your efforts @ddb. I have already gone throught [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334746/401-unauthorised-error-when-using-jquerys-get-and-gmail-api/25336197#25336197). My case is different. I am sending access token / refresh token at the time of sending an email. Another thing is that my code works most of the time, it occasionally throws 401